# Emacs (display-buffer) in frames on current desktop

Tags: emacs, xorg

When using an emacs command that uses `display-buffer` (e.g. following an error from compile-mode, calling `list-buffers`, etc.), if the buffer is open in another frame, it doesn't open in a window in the current frame, *even if the frame is not on the current desktop* (for context, I tend to use two emacs frames at a time, one visible on all desktops, and one only on a single destop).

I see in the documentation for `display-buffer` that it takes an optional argument `FRAME`, and it seems like the value `visible` would do what I want, but since I'm not calling `display-buffer` directly, I'm not sure how to set this argument. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really an answer, because my attempts at doing so got nowhere, but in general I think you'd want to advise `(display-buffer)` and change its arguments such that the only frame specifier was the value of `(current-frame)`; changing the *FRAME* argument I think isn't enough to have the desired effect, though, because the *ACTION* argument takes a list whose members' cdrs are alists in which can be specified a list of frames from which to choose -- I hacked at it a while, but had no success, so all I can say is "good luck!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older Emacs releases you can try customizing option `display-buffer-reuse-frames`.

For recent Emacs releases, i.e., if `C-h v display-buffer-alist` shows that it exists, you can try customizing that (quite complex) variable.